# In Azure Devops, can Wiki query results be produced as a PDF in a Release Pipeline?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-wiki

In Azure Devops, I'd like to set up a Release Pipeline to produce a PDF artifact of Wiki .md files which include query results.

The query results display in the Wiki pages, but from the Release Pipeline, is there any way that pandoc (or similar) can connect to the boards data and replace the query markdown syntax with the query results?

Thank you.

Comment: Hi, what do you mean the 'is there any way that pandoc (or similar) can connect to the boards'? If you want to get the workItem result by using the 'WIQL query', we can use the api: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/wiql/query%20by%20wiql?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0